# How disable button after submit

Tags: html, angular, submit, disable

I develop a form to add users, the form works, but the problem is
 when click on the button submit two successive times, the method add two users, I want the button submit (add) disable after click directly ( I work with angular 5)

HTML Code :

```html
<form [formGroup]="addfrm"> 
       ...  
         ...
       <div style="text-align:center">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="processAdd()" [disabled]="addfrm.invalid">add</button>
            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
        </div>
     </form>
```

Comment: When do you want to reEnable it? after some time, say 5 secs? , when?

Comment: please read about angular bindings

Comment: @xyz, i want after the click directly

Comment: One possibility is to use the “post/redirect/get” pattern, Or you can use javascript/jquery to disable the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a field within your component and set it to true when submitted.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="processAdd()" [disabled]="addfrm.invalid || submitted">add</button>
```

within component

```
export class MyComponent {
    submitted = false;
    ...

    processAdd() {
        this.submitted = true; 
        this.someService.post(this.addForm).subscribe(result => {
            this.submitted = false; // reset it on response from server
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **ngForm directive** :

```
<form [formGroup]="addfrm" #myform="ngForm">

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="processAdd()" [disabled]="myform.submitted">add</button>
    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
  </div>

</form>
```